# Handle an Argument varible as a Return value in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm having an issue while returning an Argument variable in Return after some manipulation.

Kindly look at the code : Note this is a sample code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Parent Routine
    ${index}    Set Variable    0
    ${index}    Set Variable      Child Routine     ${index}
    log to console    ${index}

Child Routine
    [Arguments]    ${index}
    ${index}    Set Variable      Grand Child Routine    ${index}
    #\    Some other manipulation
    [Return]    ${index}

Grand Child Routine
    [Arguments]    ${index}
    : For    ${i}     IN RANGE    1    5
    \    ${index}    Set Variable      ${index} +  1
    #\    Some other manipulation
    [Return]    ${index}

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case
    [Documentation]   Simple test for Return Value
    Parent Routine
```

Kindly look at the output window

[image]

Most probably the expected output is **`5`** but it showing **`[u'Child Routine', u'0']`**

Kindly assist me how to get the expected output.

Comment: All three answer are correct, I'm getting confusion of marking the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can use...

In your code you missed the **`Evaluate`** keyword. Before proceeding any mathematical operation we should use the **`Evaluate`** keyword.

Only change is `${index}=    Evaluate      ${index} + 1`

Finally your code is

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Parent Routine
    ${index}    Set Variable    0
    ${index}    Set Variable      Child Routine     ${index}
    log to console    ${index}

Child Routine
    [Arguments]    ${index}
    ${index}    Set Variable      Grand Child Routine    ${index}
    #\    Some other manipulation
    [Return]    ${index}

Grand Child Routine
    [Arguments]    ${index}
    : For    ${i}     IN RANGE    1    5
    \    ${index}=    Evaluate      ${index} + 1
    #\    Some other manipulation
    [Return]    ${index}

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case
    [Documentation]   Simple test for Return Value
    Parent Routine
```

Comment: All three answer are correct, I'm getting confusion of marking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Setting variables

You are using [set variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable) wrong. That keyword is for setting the value of a variable, it is not for calling other keywords.

Consider the following code:

```
${index}    Set Variable      Child Routine     ${index}
```

You are creating a list where the first value is the literal string "Child Routine" and the second value is whatever is in `${index}`, and then you are setting the variable `${index}` to that list.

If you want to call a keyword and save its return value, all you do is make that keyword the first thing after any variables. For example, in The following code we call `Child Routine`, passing it `${index}` as its only argument. The result will be saved in `${index}`.

```
${index}    Child Routine     ${index}
```

### Doing math

You can't just add "+ 1" to a variable. Robot isn't exactly a programming language. If  you want to add one to a variable you will need to use some keyword to do that. The built-in keyword [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) can be used for such purposes.

In other words, instead of this:

```
${index}    Set Variable      ${index} +  1
```

You need to do this:

```
${index}   evaluate   ${index} + 1
```

Comment: All three answer are correct, I'm getting confusion of marking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are attempting to call your user keywords by passing it to `Set Variable` which only takes in `String` values. When you pass in multiple values, you end up with a `List`.

If you want to call your user keywords and assign its return value to a variable, you want to use `Run Keyword`

```
Parent Routine
    ${index}    Set Variable    0
    ${index}    Run Keyword      Child Routine     ${index}
    log to console    ${index}

Child Routine
    [Arguments]    ${index}
    ${index}    Run Keyword      Grand Child Routine    ${index}
    #\    Some other manipulation
    [Return]    ${index}
```

Comment: All three answer are correct, I'm getting confusion of marking the answer.